# Is the set of functions from a compact to complete space complete?

Tags: general-topology

I've noticed that it's often interesting to consider what types of properties of a topology are preserved or lost when mapping between different types of spaces. This led me to wonder about spaces of functions themselves.

In this case, suppose I have two metric spaces, $(S,c)$ compact and $(T,d)$ complete, and I denote by $C(S,T)$ the set of all continuous functions from $S\to T$. I can put a metric on $C(S,T)$ defined by $\rho(f,g)=\sup_{s\in S}d(f(s),g(s))$. With this in place, is it true that $(C(S,T),\rho)$ is also complete?

Comment: It's a standard result that it is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have just provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446940/completeness-of-the-space-ce-f/2447115#2447115) links for the proofs for a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under these assumptions it is true that $(C(S,T),\rho)$ is complete.

Outline of the proof:

- Pick a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ in $C(S,T)$.
- Use the Cauchyness and the completeness of $T$ to show that the sequence $(f_n(s))$ converges for each $s\in S$.
- Show that the function $f$ defined by $f(s)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(s)$ is continuous and $(f_n)$ converges to $f$.

Munkres' *Topology (2nd edition)* has a complete proof (Theorem 43.6., page 267).

Comment: And show that $f$ is itself continuous.

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat: Thanks!