# completeness of the space $C(E,F)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, complete-spaces

Let $E$ be a compact space and $F$ a Banach space.

I want to show that  $C(E,F)$ (The space of continous functions) is a complete space.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

See, for instance, more general Theorem 2.3.4 [here](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT2400/v11/ContFunc.pdf) or even more general Proposition 1.2 [here](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/MM509/2008/notes-01.pdf), stating that if $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is a metric space then a metric space $C_b(X,Y)$ of all continuous bounded functions from $X$ to $Y$ endowed with the uniform metric is complete.